# Open PDFs From Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

As of now, I accidently clicked some sort of setting somewhere, and now all my pdfs open in adobe pdf reader instead of chrome, I have been searching on the internet for 10 minutes to change it back (I like the chrome reader much better) and no results, chrome is being updated all the time and they change the settings navigation often. Does anyone have any idea how I change it back? Please do not send me an old link/forum unless you are sure it works as of now.

Comment: @JG7. Instead of a temporary comment that might be deleted you should submit a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the PDF file type to open in Google Chrome, all you have to do is tell your OS to use Chrome instead of Adobe. I am going to assume you are using Windows 10 but I'll put a link below in case you're using macOS. In general the process will be similar.

Open **Settings** --> **Apps** --> **Default Apps** --> **Choose default app by file type** and scroll down to `.pdf` and change the application to Google Chrome.

Another way is to right click on a PDF file and then left click on **Choose another app**. Find Google Chrome and make sure to have the diologue checked that says `Always use this app to open .pdf files`.

To see more detail check out: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-ditch-microsoft-edge-your-default-pdf-reader-windows-10

For a mac take a look at: https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-change-default-pdf-viewer-mac

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should have specified the Windows 10 part. That worked, thanks!